# Create an Azure Web App and deploy html file with powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, teamcity

I want to automate the creation of an Azure We App (fd Web Site) and deploy some static content (html, js, css). That from my CI server TeamCity with Powershell.

I've playedd some with the Azure cmd-lets so I have those installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, you can use Powershell to deploy your website to Azure, e.g. your static content.

The Powershell section in the official documentation has a couple of useful links with detailed info.

- Documentation: 
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#powershell

From the Powershell section:

" E-book chapter that explains how the sample application shown in the e-book uses Windows PowerShell scripts to create an Azure test environment and deploy to it."

- http://asp.net/aspnet/overview/developing-apps-with-windows-azure/building-real-world-cloud-apps-with-windows-azure/automate-everything

"How to use Windows PowerShell deployment scripts that Visual Studio generates."

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn642480.aspx

Hope that helps! :)

- Shahed

Comment: as usual msdn links went broken